# iPhone developer program: Can I submit an enterprise application to appstore under a new developer license?

Tags: iphone

I would like to know if an application created under enterprise license can be submitted to appstore under a new standard developer license. The case is that I want my application to be tested by apple to avoid last minute surprises/rejections. My plan is that I would apply for an enterprise license, submit the app to apple (once a while while I am preparing the final app). So I would know if there are any issues with my app before hand. Once I complete the app, I would submit the same one to apple under a new standard developer account. Is this possible ?

Would my application be rejected because the same one has been approved by apple under an "in-house" category some time before?

I would also like to know if the apple approval process would be same for "in-house" apps and standard "appstore" apps ?

Thanx in advance ...

Comment: I don't think enterprise apps go through the whole Apple approval process, so I suspect this wouldn't work.

Comment: This is Apple-policy-related, not specifically programming-related. I don't think it belongs on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Apple don't test enterprise apps.

If I understand what you want to do - ie. get apple to test your app, but don't publish it on the app store until some later time then  I would suggest you submit your app as if it were going into the appstore, but put a "on sale" date that's far in the future.